# Convert date string into date time

Tags: c#

How could I convert a string in the format    (Examples are shown below) into a DateTime object. I have tried several things in attempt to convert this however, I have not been able to get it to work.

Examples of strings in the format:

```
24 Jul 2014
01 May 1988
```

Comment: How do you get this string? Is it a user input?

Answer (score 2):

From the **first [Google's](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20parse%20date%20name) "C# DateTime parse" [result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

```
string MyString = "24 Jul 2014";
DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse(MyString);
Console.WriteLine(MyDateTime); //24/07/2014 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime.Parse` method will parse most dates right out of the box:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("01 May 1988");
```

If the date format can be ambiguous, you can specify which culture settings to use:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("01 May 1988", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

For some unusual formats you can use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method to parse a specific format:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01 May 1988", "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```